# Black Screen When Installing 22.04

Tags: system-installation

Hardware:

```
CPU  3.4 GHz AMD Ryzen 9 5950X 16-Core Processor
Memory 32GB DDR4 2666MHz
GPU AMD Radeon RX 6600 8GB
Motherboard ASUS PRIME X570-PRO
```

bootable USB:

```
use balenaEtcher.app macOS to write Ubuntu-22-04-01.iso to an USB
```

then I plug it in and boot from it, I can see the screen with options on it, they are `Try or Install Ubuntu`, `Ubuntu (safe graphics)`, `OEM Install`, `Test Memory`.
And I choose `Try or Install Ubuntu`.

the monitor tells `no signal` and A black screen shows after I click `Install Ubuntu` on Grub Boot list.

Comment: Please list the exact steps you have done to try and install. How was the bot able USB made?

Comment: @David I updated the description.

Comment: I have the same problem, USB was made with Rufus, i chose MBR partition.